# How to create a US map showing maximum value of 5 different species?

Tags: r

I have the dataset (pts) like this:

```
x <- seq(-124.25,length=115,by=0.5)    
y <- seq(26.25,length=46,by=0.5)
z <- 1:5290
w <- rep(1:5,1058)
longlat <- expand.grid(x = x, y = y)
pts <- data.frame(longlat,z,w) 
names(pts) <- c( "lon","lat","data","class")
```

What I need to show is the "data", which is the maximum value,  and the category of "class" on the same US map.

Can anyone give me some ideas? Thanks so much.

Comment: What did you try so far? Where did you get stuck? Did you try `ggmap`?

Comment: I can only map the data, but do not know how to add the category information

Comment: What "category information"? You need to show an example.

Comment: category of "class" in the data pts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I have so far:

```
x <- seq(-124.25,length=115,by=0.5)    
y <- seq(26.25,length=46,by=0.5)
z <- 1:5290
w <- rep(1:5,1058)
longlat <- expand.grid(x = x, y = y)
pts <- data.frame(longlat,z,w) 
names(pts) <- c( "lon","lat","data","class")

require('ggmap')
base.map.in <- get_map(location = c(min(x),
                                    min(y),
                                    max(x),
                                    max(y)),
                       source = "osm")
# create the map object
theme_set(theme_bw(base_size = 8))
my.map <- ggmap(base.map.in) %+% pts + 
  aes(x = lon,
      y = lat) +
  geom_point(aes(color = as.factor(class),
             size = data),
             alpha = 0.5) +
  scale_size(range = c(0.5,2))
print(my.map)


ggsave(filename = "classmap.png",
       plot = my.map,
       scale = 1,
       width = 6, height = 3,
       dpi = 300)
```

and this gives me this plot:
[image]

Comment: How can we get rid of the non-us part in the plot?

Comment: The underlying map image comes from Open Street Map, and is generated by grabbing a lat / long box using `ggmap`. There are other tools to handle that part of the routine. I like `ggmap` because it plays very nicely with `ggplot`, which seemed to handle your more complex plotting requirements with ease. Another way of doing this is to make sure your data are limited to the CONUS, in which case they won't go south of the border. Finally, you may be able to find a shape file of the outline of the US and use that instead / to highlight the borders...

Comment: In stead of using size , is there a way to use color intensity to indicate data?

Comment: try putting alpha into the aes specification: `geom_point(aes(color = as.factor(class), alpha = data))`. You might want to look at the [ggplot manual](http://ggplot2.org) or the [R cookbook](http://www.cookbook-r.com) to get more ideas for how you can set up the plot using `ggplot`.

Answer (score 0):

As LostBrit suggests, why not try ggmap?

```
library(ggmap)
usmap <- ggmap(get_map(location = "US", zoom=4))
usmap + geom_point(data=pts, aes(x=lon, y=lat, size=data, color=class))
```

From there, you can play with jitter and alpha to fix up overplotting. You can use shape as the aesthetic for "class" if you first convert it to a factor with `as.factor()`

Comment: thanks, @Peter. I coded up a semi-solution that should let the OP give us some pointers.